# CoreData Swift : Crash : SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm using swift 2.0 with Xcode 7.
I want to store names from a JSON file in CoreData.

I succeed to save datas in my CoreData model, but after the value number 1272 or 1273, my app crashes.

Here is the code :

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                if let name = subJson["nom"].string {
                    print("key : \(key)")
                    self.savePerson(name)
                }
}

 func savePerson(name: String) {
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    do {
        try AppDelegate().managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
    people.append(person)
}
```

I tried to see with a breakpoint, and here is the program at the key 1272 or 1273 :

```
--> [savePerson()] try AppDelegate().managedObjectContext.save()
--> [AppDelegate] lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext =
--> [AppDelegate][managedObjectContext] let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

And here is the crash!
I checked and the name does exist, it's not nil.
I tried to put a kind of sleep on my code and it's not always at the same moment. Do you think this is a question of speed ?

Else, do you know why ?

The log is :

```
CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database at     /.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'
2015-09-22 23:59:59.774 testAlamofire2[8765:351886] CoreData: error: Encountered exception I/O error for database at /.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file' with userInfo {
NSFilePath = "/.../.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite";
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
} while checking table name from store: <NSSQLiteConnection: 0x7f8e2d677ee0>
2015-09-22 23:59:59.779 testAlamofire2[8765:351886] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///.../.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "(null)" UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14, NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at .../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'} with userInfo dictionary {
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /.../.../...SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'";
}
2015-09-22 23:59:59.780 testAlamofire2[8765:351886] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8e2d6772d0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "(null)" UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14, NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'}}}, [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "(null)" UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14, NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /.../.../.../.../SingleViewCoreData.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'}]
```

EDIT :

I found this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014115), I don't know if it helps. (old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be because your `save` statement is creating a *new instance* of the application delegate, each time you save a new person:

```
try AppDelegate().managedObjectContext.save()
```

Try using the same, existing, instance that you use earlier:

```
try managedContext.save()
```